# Busqueda dentro de un Array para imprimir valor de coincidencia

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, array

tengo un array de usuarios y quiero imprimir en un html solo el que tenga el  email: "Sincere@april.biz", como puedo hacer esa busqueda dentro del array.

```js
var user = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771"
  }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Haciéndolo con javascript puro sería algo así:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="users">
</div>
<script>
var user = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771"
  }
  }
  ];
  
var text;
for (i = 0; i < user.length; i++) { 
 if(user[i].email === "Sincere@april.biz")
  {
   //Imprimimos los elementos uno a uno:
    console.log(user[i].id);
    console.log(user[i].name);
    console.log(user[i].username);
    console.log(user[i].email);
    //Imprime el objeto JSON transformado a String
    document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(user[i], null, 4);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Simplemente recorres con un `for` el array y si `user[i].email` es igual al valor indicado se imprime (si no, no).

Además de acceder a los elementos tienes la opción de utilizar `JSON.stringify` para ver el objeto entero.

Cómo quieras representar en el DOM esos datos dependerá de tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo simplemente con un **forEach** recorres el array y preguntas si ese elemento es igual **(===)** al elemento que solo quieres imprimir.
Si es el elemento, lo imprime y si no pues que no haga nada o haga otra cosa (:

```js
const user = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771"
    }
  },
  ]
  user.forEach((user) => {
    if(user.email === 'Sincere@april.biz'){
      document.write('<p>' + user.email + '</p>')
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

También puedes utilizar `filter` para recorrer `user`

```
var email = 'Sincere@april.biz';
var result = '';

function findEmail (email) {
  var find = user.filter( function (item) {
    return item.email == email;
  })
  return find;
}

result = findEmail(email)[0];

console.log(result.name) //Leanne Graham
```

Answer (score 1):

Para el manejo de arrays puedes usar las funciones de iteración que están definidas en el prototipo de Array https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/prototype

Para abordar este ejemplo se pueden usar por ejemplo:
map, find, filter, forEach...

Por ejemplo:

```
user.map((val)=>{
    if(val.email=='Sincere@april.biz'){
        console.log(val);
    }
});
```

o

```
user.find((val)=>{return val.email=='Sincere@april.biz'})
```

o

```
user.filter((val)=>{return val.email=='Sincere@april.biz'})[0]
```

...

Para entender como usar estas funciones propias de los Arrays en javascript puesdes leer el link que dejé arriba.

Si no quieres usar estas funciones siempre puedes usar los bucles o ciclos como for o while. Por ejemplo:

```
  for(var i=0;i<user.length;i++){
    if(user[i].email=='Sincere@april.biz'){
        console.log(user[i])
    }
  }
```

o

```
  var i=0;
  while(i<user.length){
    if(user[i].email=='Sincere@april.biz'){
        console.log(user[i])
    }
    i++;
  }
```